# Write a function to build a tree from a list

Tags: f#

How can I write a function to build a tree from a list in F#?

```
 type Tree =
         | Node of (Tree * Tree)
         | leaf of int
```

If one reads the labels of the tree from left to write then they should be in the same order as the original list.

Comment: Which are the labels of the tree? If you only want to preserve the order of the list, why do you need a tree structure?

Comment: Seriously? Exactly the same question in less than two days?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints to get you started. Given your definition of `Tree`:

```
type Tree = 
    | Leaf of int
    | Node of (Tree * Tree)
```

You wish to define a function that constructs a `Tree` value from a list of integers. It's good practice to break down problems into smaller pieces, so instead of defining the *fromList* function directly you may start with a simpler function for adding a single element. To do this you simply need to consider the two cases, i.e. the two possible shapes of trees, so the stub of such a function is already given:

```
let addInt n tree =
    match tree with
    | Leaf x        -> ??
    | Node (t1,t2)  -> ??
```

Once you figured out a reasonable definition you can proceed by thinking about how to define the function which operates on lists and reuses `addInt`. This time you need to match the base cases for a list:

```
let rec addMany xs tree =
    match xs with
    | []        -> ??
    | x :: xs   -> ??
```

Once you are comfortable solving problems like this using explicit recursion, you may have a look at `List.fold` to simplify your solution.